# Add distinct (not duplicated) TComboBox items from filtered SQL column

Tags: delphi

I use `TADOQuery` to query an MSAccess table and filter the `Dept` column. It returns 5 rows.

I want to add `TComboBox` items of distinct values, which were filtered from another column (`Tip`).

In my case, the `TComboBox` has to contain 3 items. (`FAX`, `PRINTER`, `SCANNER`). What is the best way? SQL or ...?

[image: pic]

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you need the rest of the columns of data (SAP, Model, Dept)? If not, you can do it easily in your SQL. If you need the information from those columns, you can't do it with SQL, but will need to do it differently. Which one do you need?

Comment: thank you. to be more specific, there have 4 TEdit's that are filtering  table with adoquery and  3 TCombobox's that will be added to items list which were filtered by theese TEdit's. it would be good, TCombobox's were distinctly populated by any changing of dbgrid

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the other columns in the table, which was the specific question I asked. Please be specific **about that information**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply filter the SQL resultset using `DISTINCT`, for example

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Tip FROM Table WHERE Dept = 'IKTT'
```